# R server with REST API and user authentication

Tags: r, rest

I need help from more exprienced R users. I am looking for R server app with REST API. I would like to send and run R script using HTTP and retrieve results. 
The important thing is user authentication and authorization - scripts should be executed in separated workspace (like user home directory). The best solution will be user system account authentication/authorization.
Does anyone know such application?
I found application like OpenCPU but without authentication support.

In details:

r server app should be standalone application running on machine with Linux. It listen on HTTP port for request. Clients applications comunicate with server only via REST API. To execute R code, client must authenticate first using system account username and password. After succesful authentication user have access to their own home directory (or other dedicated workspace dir). User can read/writes files in workspace from R code. The R code to execute is sent as plain text in POST request. Eventualy it could be run as script from user's workspace directory. Support for full R functionality is required
The general idea is similar to RStudio Server or JupyterHub except the client is not web browser but external (for example Java) application.
Unfortunatelly I didn't found reasonable API documentation for RStudio or JupyterHub

Comment: you can build that in/on top of opencpu, fiery, plumber, etc.

Comment: Provide an example of your data can be useful for use, it is not clear what you are asking, try to make a reproducible example.

Comment: I just added detailed description

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished the same using RApache

http://rapache.net

You can run your R scripts by making a Rest call and can also pass arguments (GET and POST) to your scripts

```
<Location /helloworld>
 SetHandler r-handler 
 RFileHandler /path/helloworld.r 
</Location>
```

Here helloworld will be API endpoint and it will in turn execute the helloworld.r script

It also supports authentication as is build on top of Apache